# How to dyn_cast in LLVM to identify StoreInst?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to identify `StoreInst`. I read LLVM manual, and tried to use `dyn_cast` to do that. But the following program returns very weird result.

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override{
    for (const BasicBlock &BB : F){
        for (const Instruction &I : BB){
            const char *s = I.getOpcodeName();
            std::string str(s);
            errs()<<"at the instruction of "<<str<<"\n";
            if (const StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I))
                    errs()<<"FOUND STORE\n";
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The result is as followed. `dyn_cast` somehow returns true when the instruction is actually a CallInst. Anyone know why this happened? And how can I fix it? btw, I've installed some old versions of LLVM on the same machine, but think I compiled the pass under LLVM-7.0.0, and get the .ll file using clang-7.0.0 by `clang-7 -O0 -S -emit-llvm HelloWorld.cpp`. Would the previous installed versions affect this version? Thanks!!

```
at the instruction of call
at the instruction of call
at the instruction of ret
at the instruction of alloca
FOUND STORE
at the instruction of alloca
FOUND STORE
at the instruction of alloca
FOUND STORE 
at the instruction of store
at the instruction of store
at the instruction of store
at the instruction of call
at the instruction of call
at the instruction of ret
at the instruction of call
at the instruction of ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, since your pass is a `FunctionPass`, it runs in parallel on multiple functions, so your log messages are printed out of order.